# Q about JavaScript: how can i "reset" switch statement?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

The switch statement has different cases but for the default, the user is prompted to enter a new value.

I want that new value to be checked against the different cases. If case matches, corresponding code is executed. But otherwise, it will go to default and re-prompt.

How do I write the code to re-check the expression inside the switch statement?

```
var anyLetter; 
anyLetter = prompt("Enter one of the following letters (b, o, or h): "); 

switch(anyLetter)
{
case "b": 
case "B": 
    //code if user enters b or B
    break; 
case "o": 
case "O": 
    //code 
    break; 
case "h": 
case "H": 
    //code
    break; 
default: 
    var anyLetterAgain; 
    anyLetterAgain = prompt("Enter one of the following letters (b, o, or h): "); 
}
```

I want what the user enters for anyLetterAgain to run thru the switch statement, and continue until b, o, or h is entered. Please help! Thanks

Comment: A `while(condition)` loop around the switch would work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call the function that your switch block code is in again for case `default`.

For example:

```
function askForLetter() {
    var anyLetter; 
    anyLetter = prompt("Enter one of the following letters (b, o, or h): "); 

    switch(anyLetter){
        case "b": 
        case "B": 
            //code if user enters b or B
        break; 
        case "o": 
        case "O": 
            //code 
        break; 
        case "h": 
        case "H": 
            //code
        break; 
        default:
            askForLetter();  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it would be more appropriate to use a while loop.  For example:

```js
var good = false
while (!good) {
  var l = prompt("Enter one of the following letters (b, o, or h): ");
  if (l == 'o' || l == 'O' || l == 'b' || l == 'B' || l == 'h' || l == 'H') {
    good = true;
    MyOtherFunction(l); //handle the user input here
  } 
}
```

Just a thought...

Comment: `if({o:1,O:1,b:1,B:1,h:1,H:1}[l]){ ` is simpler and avoids multiple evals

Comment: Thanks dandavis. The code can definitely be optimized :)

Answer (score 0):

While all the answers above are correct, I need to point out one will need additional modification of the conditions when you need to include new option and second will have hard time retrieving the letter itself in this state which is easily fixable, however because of its recursive nature it might lead to stack overflow (note the irony) in some extreme scenarios.
Here is my version of the code:

```
var anyLetter = ''; 
while (anyLetter == '')
{
    anyLetter = getMyLetter();
}
console.log("MyLetter:", anyLetter);

function getMyLetter()
{
    var letter = prompt("Enter one of the following letters (b, o, or h): "); 
    switch(letter)
    {
        case "b": 
        case "B": 
        {
            //code if user enters b or B
            break; 
        }
        case "o": 
        case "O": 
        {
            //code 
            break; 
        }
        case "h": 
        case "H": 
        {
            //code
            break; 
        }

        default: 
        {
            letter = '';
        }

    }
    return letter;
}
```